# Highlight specific string in listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to highlight current playing song in listbox.
I got the currentItem of playlist.
But it does not get selected because index is always -1.

```
public void _open_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _playList.Items.Clear();
    string[] filenames = { };
    _openFile.Multiselect = true;
    _openFile.ShowDialog();
    var l1 = _playa.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("PlayList");
    foreach (var name in _openFile.FileNames)
    {
        _playList.Items.AddRange(_openFile.FileNames.ToArray());

    }

    _playListJob();
    string curItem = _playa.Ctlcontrols.currentItem.getItemInfo("Name");
    int index1 = _playList.FindString(curItem);
    if (index1 != -1)
        _playList.SetSelected(index1, true);
}
```

Can anyone help me understand what I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure  `curItem` has the correct value?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please use upper case at the start of a sentence and full stops at the end. Check the preview before posting. Line breaks in the editor only lead to line breaks in the displayed text if you enter two spaces before the line break or an empty line after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
    index1=_playList.Items.IndexOf(curItem);
    if(index1 >= 0)
    {
    _playList.SetSelected(index1, true);
    }
```

Comment: i tried that before, index is always -1 for some reason any idea why  ?

Comment: then you need to check the items in playlist, do the items get added correctly. What is the value of curItem. set a break point, inspect the values

Comment: it highlights now but i had to add index1 = 0 after the indexOf part. one problem though when the mediaplayer changes song it doesn't mark the current name

Answer (score 0):

The above solution definitely works. It is just a matter if you have added your file names correctly

```
            public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddItems();
    }

    public void AddItems()
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        string[] filenames = new[] { "music a", "music b" };

        listBox1.Items.AddRange(filenames);
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string curItem = "music a";
        int index1 = listBox1.Items.IndexOf(curItem);
        if (index1 != -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(curItem);
        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: well that doesn't work and basically the same as the first answer my problem is that i am trying to make it so when a song played a parallel name which displayed in listbox will be highlighted